# Sum random samples controlled by sliderInput

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, shiny

The only issue is the samples are not summing the Net Return column from the excel files, that is changed with the sliderInput. I tried using sum and summarise but I didn't get results. In fact, without the scale_y_continuous breaks function it plots a range of values (which is how I know it's not doing what I want). Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

UI:

```
filtered = readxl::read_excel("/Users/Filter2.xlsx")
unfiltered = readxl::read_excel("/Users/Unfilter2.xlsx")

ui = fluidPage(
  sliderInput("obs", "Number of Observations", value = 550, min = 100, max = 1000),
  plotOutput("filter")
 )
```

Server:

```
server = function(input, output) {
  output$filter = renderPlot({
  mysample = filtered[sample(1:nrow(filtered), input$obs,
                            replace=FALSE),]
  mysample2 = unfiltered[sample(1:nrow(unfiltered), input$obs,
                                replace=FALSE),]
  tbl = bind_rows(Filtered = mysample, Unfiltered = mysample2,
                  .id="type")
  #sum(mysample)
  #sum(mysample2)
  #summarise(mysample = sum(mysample),
  #          mysample2 = sum(mysample2))

  ggplot(tbl, aes(x = type, fill = type)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = Net_Return)) +
    labs(x = "Type", y = "Net Return") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, limits = c(0, 2500000))  
 })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need a `group_by` `sum` i.e.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui = fluidPage(
  sliderInput("obs", "Number of Observations", value = 550, min = 1, max = 10),
  plotOutput("filter")
)    
filtered <- mtcars[1:15,]
unfiltered <- mtcars

server = function(input, output) {
  output$filter = renderPlot({
    mysample = filtered[sample(1:nrow(filtered), input$obs,
                               replace=FALSE),]
    mysample2 = unfiltered[sample(1:nrow(unfiltered), input$obs,
                                  replace=FALSE),]
    tbl = bind_rows(Filtered = mysample, Unfiltered = mysample2,
                    .id="type") %>%
                    group_by(type) %>%
                    summarise(wt = sum(wt))

    print(nrow(tbl))
    print(tbl)
    #sum(mysample)
    #sum(mysample2)
    #summarise(mysample = sum(mysample),
    #          mysample2 = sum(mysample2))

    ggplot(tbl, aes(x = type,  fill = type)) +
      geom_col(aes(y =wt)) +
      labs(x = "Type", y = "Weight") +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(legend.position = "none") 
  })
}  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed